# Regex full text filter/search in Microsoft Graph API for O365 in request?

Tags: request, full-text-search, office365, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to add a filter in my Microsoft Graph API request on O365 data (like mails, messages, events, etc.) to only get items where certain regex triggers.

I found the `search` feature: *[Full Text Search Capabilities in Azure AD Graph API (preview)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2015/04/10/full-text-search-capabilities-in-azure-ad-graph-api-preview/)*, but it seems this feature have been removed (and it did not have regex capabilities).

> Advanced warning notice:  The Azure AD Graph team will be shutting off this preview capability.  As of September 19th 2016, this feature will no longer be available.  We’d like to hear from you if you have been using this capability, and what you think about it.  We are currently investigating some options around introducing this type of capability again at a future (unspecified) date.

I also found the `contains` filter, that is used like this: `$filter=contains(body, 'Bob')`, but I can't seem to use a regex rule in it and it doesn't seem to be able to search in the body.

**Is it possible to build a query that will only return items where a regex rule is triggered?** Worse case scenario, I will download all items and then use regex rules on them, but I would prefer to not download all those useless items if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The [Azure AD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog) and [Microsoft Graph API](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/overview) are two different APIs. At present, the Microsoft API supports the [OData Query Parameters](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/query_parameters) to help customize the response.

> Is it possible to build a query that will only return items where a regex rule is triggered?

No, it doesn't this feature. You may submit the feedback [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) if you require this feature.